# Flutter - How to place card back in the stack after left swipe

Tags: flutter, dart, swipe, swipe-gesture

I am using [swipe_stack](https://pub.dev/packages/swipe_stack).
It pretty much serves the purpose for me except that I want to place the swiped card back at the bottom of the stack on left swipe. I don't know how to achieve this.
Here is the git for this repo:
[SwipeStack](https://github.com/gmetekorkmaz/SwipeStack)
I have imported the repo in my project so I can make changes to it. However, I don't how to achieve it.

```
                  child: SwipeStack(
                key: dashboardController.swipeKeyFlashDeals,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 10,
                  bottom: 20,
                  left: 5,
                  right: 10,
                ),
                children: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].map((int index) {
                  return SwiperItem(
                      builder: (SwiperPosition position, double progress) {
                    return FlipCard(
                      direction: FlipDirection.HORIZONTAL,
                      speed: 500,
                      onFlipDone: (status) {
                        print(status);
                      },

                      /// FRONT SIDE
                      front: Material(
                        elevation: 4,
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        child: Stack(children: [
                ….
                      ]),
            ….
                      ///BACK SIDE
                      back: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        child: BackdropFilter(
                          filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                            sigmaX: 75,
                            sigmaY: 75,
                          ),
                          child: …
            ))
                }).toList(),
                visibleCount: 3,
                stackFrom: StackFrom.Right,
                translationInterval: 10,
                scaleInterval: 0.03,
                onEnd: () => debugPrint("onEnd"),
                onSwipe: (int index, SwiperPosition position) {

                  return debugPrint("onSwipe $index $position");
                },
                onRewind: (int index, SwiperPosition position) =>
                    debugPrint("onRewind $index $position"),
              ),
```

Comment: Can you include sample snippet that will reproduce the issue

Comment: I have already added the link to the code, and I have now added the code showing how I am implementing the package.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding a function to the `onSwipe` property that adds the child you are swiping, back to the first position of the SwipeStack children?

The best way should be to change the implementation of the `SwipeStack` itself. Instead of removing the child from the children's list add him back to the top of the list. And create a bool `keepChildrenOnSwipeLeft` to control that.

Comment: Yes. I tried adding it back to the stack on the onSwipe. I couldn't write the logic. 
And except for creating a bool, I also considered changing the SwipeStack itself. It's just that I am unable to achieve it technically. I don't know what changes to make to the code. Logically I know what can/should be done.